# Flask-Restless How can i get API from params not a JSON type and filter from those params?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restless

How can i get API from params not a JSON type and filter from those params?
Ex: http://localhost:5000/api/person/1?a=1&b=2&c=3﻿